# Save image loaded to my UILoader in AS3 in order to load it without internet connection

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

I've got some UIloader in my AS3 code that displays images via web link.

```
uiloader1.source = "http://www.mywebsite/image1.jpg";
uiloader2.source = "http://www.mywebsite/image2.jpg";
```

Once the user have open the app with an internet connection, I'd like him to be able to open it again without any internet connection but still have the possibility to display the images.

I thought about something like :

```
var savedImage:SharedObject;
savedImage= SharedObject.getLocal("ImagesFolder");

if (monitor.available || savedImage.data.images == "null") {

    uiloader1.source = "http://www.mywebsite/image1.jpg";
    uiloader2.source = "http://www.mywebsite/image2.jpg";

    savedImage.data.loader1 = uiloader1.source;
    savedImage.data.loader2 = uiloader2.source;

}

else {

    uiloader1.source = savedImage.data.loader1;
    uiloader2.source = savedImage.data.loader2;

}
```

But it doesn't work as it saves the link of the image and not the actual image.

Any idea how can I save the images into a file and told `uiloader1.source` and `uiloader2.source` to load them ?

**EDIT**

So I've tried that :

```
uiloader10.source = "http://www.myWebsite/image1.jpg";
uiloader10.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {

    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(uiloader10.width,uiloader10.height);
    bitmapData.draw(uiloader10);
    var jpgencoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    var mybyte:ByteArray = jpgencoder.encode(bitmapData);
    var myfile:FileReference = new FileReference();

    myfile.save(mybyte,"test.jpg");

}
```

It seems to work (test it on desktop, not on my phone device yet).

**1/But you think I shouldn't do that for an AIR app ?** 
Could you show me the code I should change in order to make it more "app compatible" please ?

**2/ How do I do to load the file in a Uiloader (how can retrieve automatically the path ?"**
Example : I've tried `uiloader11.source = "test.jpg";` 
but error : `Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: app:/test.jpg`

Comment: 1. If you publish for **AIR** - go for **AIR**, it has more capabilities. And for sake's sake, a tad bit effort? Google > air save file > first link. 2. Then the file URL is not "app:/test.jpg" and I obviously have no idea where you saved it. Probably you should compare **FileReference.name** (what is it after you saved the file) and **File.applicationDirectory.nativePath**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it stores the URL as you instructed, why should it do otherwise?

You can store a limited list of data types in **SharedObject**:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#data

So, after loading your actual images from the web you are to store their content as a **ByteArray** which could be found in **Loader.loaderInfo.bytes**:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#loaderInfo
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#bytes

If that does not work you have plan B to load image source with **URLLoader** by setting **URLLoader.dataFormat** to **URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY**.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#dataFormat

Then on the second start you can restore these images from **SharedObject** with **Loader.loadBytes()** method:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes()

**P.S.** If your app runs under **AIR** environment you actually can read/write files to local storage rather than spam **SharedObject** with data that are not supposed to go there. Use **File.applicationStorageDirectory** to locate the app storage folder and **FileStream,open()**, **FileStream.readBytes()**, **FileStream.writeBytes()** to open, read, write files respectively.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html